# QQuickItem::clipRect обрезает QSGNode в QQuickItem::updatePaintNode()

Tags: c++, qt, qtquick

Я сделал QML компонент на основе `QQuickItem`. Переопределил в нем метод `QQuickItem::clipRect()` для того, чтобы обрезать вложенные компоненты по определенной границе, которая меньше размера самого компонента. В методе `QQuickItem::updatePaintNode()` я рисую кастомный QSGNode на основе `QSGGeometryNode/QSGGeometry/QSGFlatColorMaterial`. Проблема в том, что при необходмой мне геометрии в `QQuickItem::clipRect()` и `clip: true` у компонента, отрисованный `QSGNode` обрезается по границе заданной в `QQuickItem::clipRect()`.

Что нужно сделать, чтобы `QSGNode` рисовался за пределами `QQuickItem::clipRect()`?